# python：exeで実行すると Cannot load native module "Cypto.Ciper_raw_ecb': Not Found

Tags: python, pyinstaller

pycryptodomeをインストールし、PKCS1+Base64変換のプログラムを組みました。

ソースレベルで実行したときは正常動作しましたが、`pyinstaller hogehoge.py --onefile` にてexe化し、hogehoge.exeを実行すると以下のエラーになります。
恐らくpycryptdomeのインストール位置が見えてないのかなと思います。いくつか検索したのですが解決に至っていないので、解決方法わかりますでしょうか。

**実行環境:**
Python 3.10.1
pycriptodome 3.16.0

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
Cannot load native module 'Crypto.Cipher._raw_ecb': Not found '_raw_ecb.cp310-win32.pyd', Not found '_raw_ecb.pyd'
```

Comment: 参考: [How to build executable with pyinstaller that uses pycryptodome?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46799167/2322778)

Comment: 問題の発生するソースコードとPyInstallerに指定するオプションや設定ファイル等の情報および検索・試行した記事や結果といった、他の人が問題を再現・調査出来る情報を質問記事に追記してみてください。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: ソースレベルで実行したPythonとPyInstallerで実行したPythonのインストール先が異なり、インストールされているパッケージが違うときに発生しやすいですね。

Comment: onefileオプションなしのときにどうなるかも試してみたほうがいいです。pycryptodomeを取り込んでのPyInstallerでのビルドは当方では成功しておりますので、貴方の環境下で何らかの問題があると思われます。

Answer (score 0):

解決しました。最初のお答えを参考にpyinstallerをバージョンアップしてビルドしたら無事動作しました。
最初から確認すればよかったです
ありがとうございました